# vim: assign variable to return value of ex call?

Tags: vim

I want to have vim .vimrc do something like:

```
let root = :pwd
```

and the variable `root` will have memorized that "pwd" that vim was in at that moment. How do I do this?

Another person asked this question, but another solution was found, so the question was never really answered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540524/vim-call-an-ex-command-set-from-function)

### Using variables

Also, once I assign root to a value, how do I do the following:

```
:cd root
```

Every time I do that, vim gives me the following error:

```
E344: Can't find directory "root" in cdpath
E472: Command failed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:let root = getcwd()
:exe 'cd ' . root
```

There are probably nicer ways to do this (especially the last part) but it works.

Comment: also quite useful: `:cd %:h` (_change to directory of file in current_)

Comment: only short thing I can think of: `:exe 'cd'root`

Comment: @sehe, can you explain that `%:h` notation?

Comment: Also, to make sure I understand, there is no way to call ex commands in functions or let statments or anything. I have to scrounge around and find the inbuilt function that does the same thing and use that. Correct?